# How to check correlation of levels between two variables?

Tags: r, correlation

I have two columns, A & B, in a data frame called X. A has 38 levels and B has 3.

How can I check the correlation between each of A's 38 levels and each of B's 3 levels?  Thanks.

Comment: Please review [mcve] and in particular show your input but first cut the problem down to size so it is minimal.

Answer (score 2):

If A and B are ordered then we can compute their rank correlation (i.e. the correlation of their ranks):

```
dd <- data.frame(A = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), 
                 B = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y")) # test data
with(dd, cor(rank(A), rank(B)))
## [1] 0.8164966
```

or if not then we can compute correlations between each pair of levels:

```
mA <- model.matrix(~ A - 1, dd)
mB <- model.matrix(~ B - 1, dd)
cor(mA, mB)
##            Bx         By
## Aa  0.7071068 -0.7071068
## Ab  0.0000000  0.0000000
## Ac -0.7071068  0.7071068
```

In this latter case if we want a single number we could look at the canonical correlation which is the highest correlation between linear functions of the two sets of variables.  (We could also just ignore the ordering and then apply this to the first case too.)

```
cancor(mA, mB)$cor
## [1] 0.8164966
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solution, I have not been able to find it on any of the other forums. However, I wanted to ask, is it actually correlation or mutual information?

To me, it appears to be pointwise mutual information (more information on PMI can be accessed at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information). The main difference of Mutual information and Pointwise mutual information is how MI is calculated on a distribution and thus cannot be negative. Whereas PMI is pointwise and can have negative scores to show negative association between points.

Answer (score 1):

The term "correlation" is used for variables that are numeric in character. If you are examining the joint relationship of two categorical variables (with factor levels, then you can look at a cross-tabulation with `table`:

```
AB.tbl <- with(X, table, A,B))
AB.tbl
```

To see whether this is plausibly a non-random association you can use a `chisq.test` which gives you an overall test of association:

```
chisq.test(AB.tbl)
```